# Locate the centroid of the plane area shown

Tags: mechanical-engineering

QUESTION: [image]

I need help, can someone help me show how we get the solution as stated in the question; as i am trying my very best to solve.

Comment: Try dividing the figure into two triangles and a rectangle, cutting horizontally 54mm from x-axis.

Comment: Copy the examples in the textbook

Comment: homework questions are not off topic, but lazy cut pastes showing no effort to do anything are.

Comment: @JemEripol or 3 triangles. But yes given the dimensions yours is easier.

Comment: @joojaa can you please show me the dividing of these shapes then i will continue from there since that is what making me finding the way through very difficult.

Comment: @Surdz, you should try to break the figure into something which you are more convenient to solve. Most engineers differ in preference regarding the cutting so you should try to develop your own "taste" in solving such problems. :)

Comment: @joojaa, how can I cut it into three triangles?  I am not really a fan of triangles in cutting figures. LOL

Comment: @JemEripol draw two lines from upper right corner one to origin and one to the remaining far corner (incidenttally in CG that is called a triangle fan :). Triangles are more general, for polygons, and easy enough to handle if you use cross product and vector formulations.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that you can break a object into pieces.  The centroid of the whole object is the weighted centroids of the pieces.  Since this is a planar object, the centroids of the pieces are weighted according to the area of those pieces.

Your object is regular enough so that it can be broken into pieces for which centroids can be easily found, like rectangles and triangles.